# VBA to Copy Text String from PDF

Tags: vba, pdf

I've started using the following code to identify a text string in a PDF. It works great, however, I'm wondering if there is a way to copy the entire row from the PDF into excel once the text has been found?  I'm not very familiar with using VBA code to pull from PDFs so I'm kind of stuck at the moment.  Any help is appreciated!!

---

```
Sub AcrobatFindText2() 

'variables
Dim Resp 'For message box responses
Dim gPDFPath As String
Dim sText As String 'String to search for
Dim sStr As String 'Message string
Dim foundText As Integer 'Holds return value from "FindText" method

'hard coding for a PDF to open, it can be changed when needed.
gPDFPath = "C:\Users\Me\Documents\test.pdf"

'Initialize Acrobat by creating App object
Set gApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App", "")
gApp.Hide

'Set AVDoc object
Set gAvDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

' open the PDF
If gAvDoc.Open(gPDFPath, "") Then
sText = "Designation"
'FindText params: StringToSearchFor, caseSensitive (1 or 0), WholeWords (1 or 0), 'ResetSearchToBeginOfDocument (1 or 0)
foundText = gAvDoc.FindText(sText, 1, 0, 1) 'Returns -1 if found, 0 otherwise

Else ' if failed, show error message
Resp = MsgBox("Cannot open" & gPDFPath, vbOKOnly)

End If

If foundText = -1 Then

'compose a message
sStr = "Found " & sText
Resp = MsgBox(sStr, vbOKOnly)
Else ' if failed, 'show error message
Resp = MsgBox("Cannot find" & sText, vbOKOnly)
End If

gApp.Show
gAvDoc.BringToFront

End Sub
```

---

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot of your file? I'm just wondering if there is a reason why you want to do this programmatically as you can export your PDF into excel format

Comment: The files are basically financial statements - I want to find the line for "Revenue", for example, and copy the text next to it.  The reason I want to copy the entire line id because I won't know how many numbers will follow the "Revenue" identifier - ie: $10,000 (5 length) or $200,000 (6 length).  If there's a better way of doing this I'm all ears!

Comment: @Zac [link](http://imgur.com/zM3dLhL) <-- that is an example.  I want to grab Row 5, Column 5's text (which can be found on page ## of a PDF) and looking for the best way of doing so for any line item I need.